# Calculating total score from correct answers where each correct answer is worth 5 marks

Tags: vb.net

i appreciate you so far, my question is, i am trying to create an aptitude test with 5 questions on separate forms, each question on a form has 4 radio buttons, my question is, at the end of the test, how would i add up the total score of the user provided one question is 5 marks

Public Class Form2

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        'MsgBox("Thats wrong, read the questions again", 1)
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Hide()


    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        'MsgBox("THATS RIGHT, you can move on now..", 1)
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked Then
        'MsgBox("wrong answer", 1)
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked Then
        'MsgBox("DATS WRONG, YOU FALL FOR THE TRICK???", 1)
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Hide()


    Else
        MsgBox("please select one answer", 1)

    End If
    'RadioButton1.Checked = False
    'RadioButton2.Checked = False
    'RadioButton3.Checked = False
    'RadioButton4.Checked = False
    'If RadioButton1.Checked = False Then
    '    MsgBox("abeg write sometin")
    'End If
End Sub
```

End Class

code for checking the result is
Public Class Form7

```
Dim res1, res2, res3, res4, res5, total As Integer


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


    If Form2.RadioButton2.Checked Then
        res1 = 5
        total = total + res1
    ElseIf Form2.RadioButton1.Checked Then
        res1 = 0
        total = total + res1
    ElseIf Form2.RadioButton3.Checked Then
        res1 = 0
        total = total + res1
    ElseIf Form2.RadioButton4.Checked Then
        res1 = 0
        total = total + res1


        'ElseIf Form2.RadioButton1.Checked Then
        '    res1 = 0


        If Form3.RadioButton1.Checked Then
            res2 = 5
            total = total + res2
        ElseIf Form3.RadioButton2.Checked Then
            res2 = 0
            total = total + res2
        ElseIf Form3.RadioButton3.Checked Then
            res2 = 0
            total = total + res2
        ElseIf Form3.RadioButton4.Checked Then
            res2 = 0
            total = total + res2
            'ElseIf Form3.RadioButton2.Checked Then
            '    res2 = 0
            If Form4.RadioButton3.Checked Then
                res3 = 5
                'ElseIf Form4.RadioButton1.Checked Then
                '    res3 = 0
                If Form5.RadioButton4.Checked Then
                    res4 = 5
                    'ElseIf Form5.RadioButton1.Checked Then
                    '    res4 = 0
                    If Form6.RadioButton3.Checked Then
                        res5 = 5
                    ElseIf Form6.RadioButton1.Checked Then
                        res5 = 0
                    ElseIf Form6.RadioButton2.Checked Then
                        res5 = 0
                    ElseIf Form6.RadioButton4.Checked Then
                        res5 = 0
                        'ElseIf Form6.RadioButton1.Checked Then
                        '    res5 = 0
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If





    'total = (res1 + res2 + res3 + res4 + res5)

    MessageBox.Show(total)
End Sub
```

End Class
but its not working...

Comment: Please edit your question title. It must give a clue of what the problem is.

Comment: Out of interest, do the 5 questions need to be on separate forms?

Comment: yea, the five questions must be on the same form

Comment: on seperate forms rather...

Comment: thanks guys, i have figure it out already... yipeeeee